# Netty decoder throws IndexOutOfBounsException while writing string

Tags: java, netty

stackoverthrowers. I'm currently writing some network stuff using netty, which has this schema:

- cluster

  - client 1
  - client 2
  - client 3

When I start client, it connects to a cluster and cluster sends my object, called ServerDataPacket to all connected clients. All the clients receives ServerDataPacket object successfully.
However, the problem starts when I do some action in one of clients. For example I do something in client 1, it sends another object to a cluster, cluster receives and sends object ServerDataPacket again to all clients. All clients receives this object, but not client 1, which instead of full information throws this error:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 501, length: 15 (expected: range(0, 512))
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 501, length: 15 (expected: range(0, 512))
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkIndex0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1359)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkIndex(AbstractByteBuf.java:1354)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.internalNioBuffer(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:331)
        at io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.decodeString(ByteBufUtil.java:614)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.toString(AbstractByteBuf.java:1213)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.getCharSequence(AbstractByteBuf.java:492)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readCharSequence(AbstractByteBuf.java:497)
        at net.novaplay.common.network.bungee.ServerDataPacket.read(ServerDataPacket.java:45)
        at net.novaplay.common.netty.packet.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:29)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
        ... 16 more
```

An error is caused by decoding string in bytebuffer

```
    @Override
    public void read(ByteBuf buf){
            int length = buf.readInt();
            String id = (String)buf.readCharSequence(length, Charsets.UTF_8); //here i got an error
    }
```

My netty decoder:

```
public class PacketDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf byteBuf, List<Object> output) throws Exception {
        while(byteBuf.readableBytes() > 0) {
            int id = byteBuf.readInt();
            if(NettyHandler.DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Packet ID: " + id);
            }
            Class<? extends Packet> packetClass = PacketHandler.PACKETS.get(id);
            if(packetClass == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Couldn't find packet by id " + id);
            }
            Packet packet = packetClass.newInstance();
            int length = byteBuf.readInt();
            packet.uniqueId = UUID.fromString( (String) byteBuf.readCharSequence(length, Charsets.UTF_8)); //memory leak here, view UPD.2
            packet.read(byteBuf); //memory leak here, view UPD.2
            output.add(packet);
            if(NettyHandler.DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Packet successfully has been decoded");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and encoder:

```
public class PacketEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<Packet> {
    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Packet packet, ByteBuf byteBuf) throws Exception {
        int id = PacketHandler.PACKETS.indexOf(packet.getClass());
        if(NettyHandler.DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Packet ID: " + id);
        }
        if(id == -1) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Couldn't find id of packet " + packet.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        UUID uuid = packet.getUniqueId();
        byteBuf.writeInt(id);
        byteBuf.writeInt(uuid.toString().length());
        byteBuf.writeCharSequence(uuid.toString(), Charsets.UTF_8);
        packet.write(byteBuf);
        if(NettyHandler.DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Packet successfully has been encoded");
        }
    }
}
```

After client 1 receives this error, then when I send something from cluster, it receives all clients except client 1.

Is there any idea why client can behave so strange?

UPD.: I forgot to mention, that my objects are identified by numeric ID, which is same in decoding and encoding. But when this error appears, this packet gets some weird ID like 1113941079

UPD.2.: Now I enabled deeper debugger and sent this object to 2 clients. Second client receives it normal, but first client gots memory leak:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(512) + length(4) exceeds writerIndex(512): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 512, widx: 512, cap: 512)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(512) + length(4) exceeds writerIndex(512): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 512, widx: 512, cap: 512)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1395)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readInt(AbstractByteBuf.java:766)
        at net.novaplay.common.network.bungee.ServerDataPacket.read(ServerDataPacket.java:45)
        at net.novaplay.common.netty.packet.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:29)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
        ... 16 more
Packet ID: 9
Got io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:335)
        at io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.decodeString(ByteBufUtil.java:605)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.toString(AbstractByteBuf.java:1213)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.getCharSequence(AbstractByteBuf.java:492)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readCharSequence(AbstractByteBuf.java:497)
        at net.novaplay.common.netty.packet.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:28)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is caused by how the data is sent over the network. The data received by `ByteToMessageDecoder` is not guaranteed to be consist entirely of complete packets - you might receive only part of a packet, or multiple complete packets followed by am incomplete one. There are two simple ways you can resolve this:

- add a check in your decoder (as the first thing in the body of the `while` loop) to ensure that the buffer contains a full packet, and exit without modifying the buffer's `readerIndex` if there aren't enough readable bytes.
- add a [`LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) to the pipeline, before your packet decoder. This will read and discard the length prefix automatically, and pass your decoder one buffer for each length-prefixed section. Note that this will require you to add another length prefix at the beginning of your packet, containing the length of your entire packet (with ID, UUID, as well as the actual packet body).

Bonus: your method of encoding a string is incorrect. `ByteBuf#writeCharSequence` returns the number of bytes written, and `ByteBuf#readCharSequence` requires the size of the string in *bytes*, not in characters. It works fine for your use case because a UUID's text representation only consists of single-byte characters, but generally you should use something like this:

```
int lengthPrefixIndex = buffer.writerIndex();
int length = buffer.writeInt(-1).writeCharSequence(text, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
buffer.setInt(lengthPrefixIndex, length);
```

Also, `ByteBuf#readCharSequence` isn't guaranteed to return a `String`, you should remove the cast and replace it with a call to `toString()`.